# Yii2. Не видны некоторые параметры POST запроса

Tags: php, yii2, post

При большом объёме передаваемых данных с клиента на сервер, некоторые параметры, которые я передаю в теле POST запроса не видно на сервере. Я передаю через POST запрос достаточно большую древовидную структуру, а также ещё несколько параметров. И когда объём этой структуры достаточно большой, то остальные параметры сервер по какой-то причине не видит, а если объём структуры маленький, то эти параметры видны серверу. Я менял `post_max_size` в `php.ini`, но это не помогло. В чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в другом. Нужно менять **[max_input_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)**, т.е. сколько входных переменных может быть принято в одном запросе.  Но я рекомендовал бы другой подход: данные складываем в JSON строку и отправляем одной переменной. На сервере делаем `json_decode`. Количество передаваемых переменных: 1. Дёшево и сердито. И если на серваке нельзя менять настройки php.ini - ещё один плюс такого подхода.

Answer (score 1):

Решил свою проблему. Нужно было изменить поле `max_input_vars` на большее значение, чем было.